# MySQL grant file permission to a user

Tags: mysql

MySQL Grant file permission to a user

I need to give file permission to a user in the MySQL database.

Syntax:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'uname'@'localhost' identified by 'pwd';
```

I get this error .Im not a roor user .

```
Error Code: 1045

Access denied for user 'uname'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Did you flush the privileges?

Comment: I tried flush privileges i got this error

Comment: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Did you get the 1045 error after the grant command, or while trying to do it as `uname` user?

Comment: after executing the GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'someuname'@'localhost' identified by 'somepwd'; i got this 1045 error

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned:

> Im not a roor user .

Your user has to have the `GRANT OPTION` privilege in order to grant permissions to other users.  Try as root, or have the root user grant the `GRANT OPTION` to your user.

```
mysql> grant all privileges on dbname.* to 'yourusername'@'%' ;
```

is not enough; you need:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on dbname.* to 'yourusername'@'%' with grant option;
```

Comment: Only root users can have GRANT?

Comment: That's not what I said at all. The user attempting to grant the permissions has to have been give permissions `WITH GRANT OPTION`.